# Update fragment from activity

Tags: android-fragments

I have a activity which have two fragments.
Activity receives broadcast events for the two fragments.
One fragment has a image button and text view. When the image button is clicked an event is send to the server and server responds back with live broadcast event.

We receive the response in activity and I need to update the UI of the fragment(the image button needs to be changed with another image)

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_window_lock, container, false);
        updateUI(view);

        return view;
    }

    public void updateUI(View view){

        String lockName;
        final String lockState;
        final boolean state;

        final ImageButton singleLockImage = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.single_lock_image);
        final TextView lockNameText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.single_lock_name);
        final TextView lockStateText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.single_lock_state);
        final ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.singleLockProgress);

            doorLock = LockState.getValue();

        lockName = doorLock.getName();
        if (doorLock.isLocked()) {
            lockState = getActivity().getString(R.string.door_locks_locked);
            singleLockImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.doorlocks_single_locked);
            state = true;
        } else {
            lockState = getActivity().getString(R.string.door_locks_unlocked);
            singleLockImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.doorlocks_single_unlocked);
            state = false;
        }

        lockNameText.setText(lockName);
        lockStateText.setText(lockState);
        singleLockImage.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        getActivity().changeState(state);
                    }
                }
        );

    }
```

I thought to call updateUI, which will get the new state from the cache saved after the broadcast event received in Activity, but I am not sure how to pass (view)

Answer (score 0):

Use FragmentActivity instead.

in FragmentActivity  :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.news_articles);

        // Create an instance of ExampleFragment
        TestFragment0 firstFragment = new TestFragment0();

        // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an Intent,
        // pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
        firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
}
```

in FragmentActivity for fragments :

```
TestFragment0 firstFragment0 = new TestFragment0();
firstFragment0.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,firstFragment0).commit();
```

Comment: Activity Oncreate I am calling the beginTransaction... Do I have to call it again when there is an update form broadcast receivers?

Comment: When the fragment is called again, the progress bar is still visible even after I set the visibility gone